# ls and dir doesn't show anything on debian 10

Tags: directory, debian, ls, debian-buster

I've installed debian 10 32bit on a laptop and tried to use ls but then it prints nothing.
And when I use ls -a I get this:

```
root@acer-aspire-one:~# ls  //This prints nothing
root@acer-aspire-one:~# ls -a
.  ..  .bashrc  .profile
```

And dir doesn't show anything either

```
root@acer-aspire-one:~# dir  //This prints nothing
root@acer-aspire-one:~# dir -a
.  ..  .bashrc  .profile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current path is `~`, which is the current user's (root) home folder.
That folder is empty an a fresh installation apart from a few hidden files which `ls -a` is showing.

So `ls` is doing its job.

To make it list a specific path, for example the `/`, you can run `ls /` or first `cd` into that path like this:

```
cd /
ls
```

Comment: Thanks I thought that the root directory was full of stuff like in kali